# How to center an image in Java?

Tags: java, canvas

I want to center an existing triangle. The prompt asks for the base of the triangle to be the length of the canvas and the peak to be touching the top and centered. It's for a class and the code was given.

```
public class Triangle {
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int xPosition;
    private int yPosition;
    private String color;
    private boolean isVisible;

    public Triangle() {
        height = 270;
        width = 270;
        xPosition = 120;
        yPosition = 120;
        color = "green";
        isVisible = false;
    }

    public void makeVisible() {
        isVisible = true;
        draw();
    }

    public void makeInvisible() {
        erase();
        isVisible = false;
    }

    public void moveRight() {
        moveHorizontal(20);
    }

    public void moveLeft() {
        moveHorizontal(-20);
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        moveVertical(-20);
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        moveVertical(20);
    }

    public void moveHorizontal(int distance) {
        erase();
        xPosition += distance;
        draw();
    }

    public void moveVertical(int distance) {
        erase();
        yPosition += distance;
        draw();
    }

    public void slowMoveHorizontal(int distance) {
        int delta;

        if(distance < 0) {
            delta = -1;
            distance = -distance;
        }
        else {
            delta = 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
            xPosition += delta;
            draw();
        }
    }

    public void slowMoveVertical(int distance) {
        int delta;

        if(distance < 0) {
            delta = -1;
            distance = -distance;
        }
        else  {
            delta = 1;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < distance; i++) {
            yPosition += delta;
            draw();
        }
    }

    public void changeSize(int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        erase();
        height = newHeight;
        width = newWidth;
        draw();
    }

    public void changeColor(String newColor) {
        color = newColor;
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {
        if(isVisible) {
            Canvas canvas = Canvas.getCanvas();
            int[] xpoints = { xPosition, xPosition + (width/2), xPosition + width };
            int[] ypoints = { yPosition + height, yPosition, yPosition + height};
            canvas.draw(this, color, new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, 3));
            canvas.wait(10);
        }
    }

    private void erase() {
        if(isVisible) {
            Canvas canvas = Canvas.getCanvas();
            canvas.erase(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.
Please, don't ask for a solution to your homework, try to find a good approach by yourself in order to become a better developer ;-)

Comment: removed redundant comments

Answer (score 1):

The center of your triangle will be at

```
xPosition + (width / 2)
yPosition + (height / 2)
```

To "center", you need to moveHorizontal/moveVertical until the center of your triangle is at the center of the space it is to be centered in